# What is the best order to watch The Lion King films?

Tags: suggested-order, the-lion-king, the-lion-king-ii-simbas-pride, the-lion-king-1.5

I have only watched *The Lion King* and I want to watch *The Lion King II* and *The Lion King 1½*, probably in a marathon with the original film, which neither I nor my wife have seen for more than 10 years so we probably forgot most of it.

As I know *The Lion King 1½* takes place at the same time as *The Lion King*, should I watch it between the first and second films? Or does it make more sense to watch the films in release order?

Comment: The Lion King 1/2 is part of the story told from the perspective of Timon and Pumba, so it needs to be watched after The Lion King so you have a grasp of the events it refers to (and so it doesn't require spoiler alerts everywhere).

Comment: I don't remember the other movies adding more to the first one. Maybe you could just watch only the original movie?

Answer (score 5):

There is not really any best order, as you already know *The Lion King* is the first film in franchise and *The Lion King II: Simba's Pride* is the sequel, so that's the order which matters. *The Lion King 1½* take place before, during and after *The Lion King*, so you should watch it after *The Lion King* but not necessarily before or after *The Lion King II*.